# how to make a numpy array from a list of list of lists

Tags: python, numpy

Right now I have a list of lists of lists that contain coordinates of different groups.
Ex. list = [ [ [0,3],[4,1],[2,3] ], [ [2,5],[41,12],[2,3] ] ]

I want to make a numpy array out of each group of coordinates, but I do not know how to convert this list. In my case, the number of groups is always changing, so is there anyway to loop through my list and make len(list) number of numpy arrays?

Comment: Did you try ```np_array = np.array(list)```? After that you can reshape it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `np.array` on your input, for example:

```
data = [[[0, 3], [4, 1], [2, 3]], [[2, 5], [41, 12], [2, 3]]]
array = np.array(data)

array.shape
```

Output:

```
(2, 3, 2)
```

It's fine if the number of groups (which I take to mean the number of elements in the outer list) changes, as long as the shape of the inner lists does not.

The shape of the result, in general, will be `(len(data), 3, 2)`.